# Display the execution process in the separate TXT File Auto Hot Key

Tags: .net, autohotkey

My Requirement is When i execute my script i want the log information to be appended into separate txt file , But the issue is when i append the log info to the appended file loop is occurring many times instead of appending the log info only once . Below is my AHK Script Code

```
#SingleInstance force
#Persistent

Run, C:\Pangaea\Software\SVN\TortoiseSVN-1.8.8.25755-x64-svn-1.8.10.msi
SetTimer, Check, 1000 
return

Check:
SetControlDelay -1

IfWinActive, ("ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClasses,&Next") 

ControlClick, &Next, ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass

FileAppend,
(
Hello World
), C:\Users\sk185462\Desktop\SVN TASK\New folder\My File.txt


IfWinActive, ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass,Remove Installation

ControlClick, Remove Installation, ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass

IfWinActive, ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass, &Remove

ControlClick, &Remove,ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass

IfWinActive, ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass, &Finish 

ControlClick, &Finish,ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass

IfWinNotExist, ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass

ExitApp
```

And Here is my appended text file :

Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World

Loop Occurring Many times Instead of appending Only once but in the file append i had given only single text "Hello World"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate the Log information in .txt file when executing .AHK Script in Auto Hot Key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443610/generate-the-log-information-in-txt-file-when-executing-ahk-script-in-auto-hot)

Answer (score 0):

Always use proper indentation:

```
IfWinActive, ("ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClasses,&Next") 
    ControlClick, &Next, ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass

FileAppend,
(
Hello World
), C:\Users\sk185462\Desktop\SVN TASK\New folder\My File.txt

IfWinActive, ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass,Remove Installation
    ControlClick, Remove Installation, ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass
IfWinActive, ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass, &Remove
    ControlClick, &Remove,ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass
```

etc. Now it's easier to see why `FileAppend` gets called multiple times: It is not part of the above if statement.

For clarification: An `if`-statement (`if()`, `ifWinActive`, ...) only considers the ONE next step. If you want to make multiple statements dependent on the `if`, use braces:

```
IfWinActive, ("ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClasses,&Next") 
{
    FileAppend,
    (
    Hello World
    ), C:\Users\sk185462\Desktop\SVN TASK\New folder\My File.txt
    ControlClick, &Next, ahk_class MsiDialogCloseClass
}
```